# How to get a directory from a path list?

Tags: sqlite, file, path, filetree

In table `data` directories and files are stored as complete paths:

| rowid | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c:/data/ |
| 2 | c:/data/test.txt |
| 3 | c:/data/sub1/ |
| 4 | c:/data/sub1/test.dat |

To get all items of a folder (directories and files) *without* the content of the sub-directories my approach failed. It returns content of sub-directories, too:

```
SELECT rowid FROM data WHERE path LIKE 'c:/data/'%;
```

result: 1, 2, 3, 4

expected result: 1, 2, 3

I then tried to check if second part of the string contains no "/" for files, or one "/" for sub-directories, failed.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Comment: This approach is NOT going to scale very well. What happens when the directory depth is 8 or 9 levels? You need to write a user-defined parsing function or use JSON to structure the paths, or something else.